# RavenDB Null and 0 order by issue

Tags: ravendb

I have a question regarding how to properly order by in RavenDB.

My dataset contains distance from a location to the airport.
If the field is null, the distance is unknown.

When I do the orderby

```cs
Queryable.OrderBy(home => home.DistanceAirport);
```

It values 0 and null equally, and returns the result like this:

```
DistanceAirPort: null
DistanceAirPort: 0
DistanceAirPort: null
DistanceAirPort: 1
```

Instead I want to achieve a result where null becomes the last result.

```
DistanceAirPort: 0
DistanceAirPort: 1
DistanceAirPort: null
DistanceAirPort: null
```

If anyone has any insights, please let me know.

Comment: Did you try with alphanumeric ordering ? <br/>
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/Csharp/indexes/querying/sorting#alphanumeric-ordering

Answer (score 1):

You can create a **custom sorter** and send it to your server: 

Docs:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/indexes/querying/sorting#creating-a-custom-sorter

Sample test:
https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/29c0212bfdaa0609c30a7ecbde0d3681485134c6/test/SlowTests/Issues/RavenDB_8355.cs#L134